# Are government income and government employee wages counted in GDP? (income approach)

Tags: gdp, government

The Wikipedia article does not include it nor exclude it.

Comment: Is there any sort of income that is *not* counted in the income approach?

Comment: @denesp The [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gross_domestic_product) writes only "Corporate profits".

Comment: No, it gives [five categories](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gross_domestic_product#Income_approach).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The wages of government workers are counted as wages of individuals in the income measure of GDP. If the Government trades, then surpluses or profits of these activities are counted as income in the income measure of GDP.

If GDP is being measured at market prices then some indirect taxes (on production or on imports, less any subsidies) are also taken into account; other taxes such as income taxes are not

Meanwhile Government payments of wages in its non-trading activities are counted as government consumption in the expenditure measure of GDP and this amount also counts as Government production in the the production measure of GDP